# Where can I ask a question about Windows Mail?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, windows-7

I have a question about Windows Mail, as part of the online Office 365. Is there a suitable SE site to ask my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) is the site you are looking for if the question is about Office 365.

From their [help](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application

If it is about the Windows Mail application, check [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Their [help](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) says:

> computer software

Make sure your question is on-topic there, so read the help center!